# Concatenated ESRI transformation names

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

For example the `arcpy.ListTransformation` function returns a list of transformation methods.  Some of the methods are concatenated i.e "WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983_2011 + NAD_1927_To_WGS_1984_79_CONUS".

I am wondering what this means for how these transformations applied with the `arcpy.Geometry.projectAs` function?  Is one method used to transform the points, then the next method transforms that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll happen more directly than that. The coordinates are stripped out of the geometry feature and sent to the projection engine in multiple processes. For instance, if the input data is in a projected coordinate reference system (projCRS A), the output data is in a different projCRS B, the input geogCRS AG is NAD83 (2011), and the output geogCRS BG is NAD 1927, here are the steps (processes):

1. ProjCRS A is unprojected to geogCRS AG, NAD83 (2011)
2. GeogCRS AG is transformed to WGS84 using the first transformation, in the reverse direction
3. GeogCRS BG is transformed to NAD 1927 using the second transformation, also in the reverse direction
4. GeogCRS BG is projected to projCRS B

If the data's raster instead, the process still includes steps like these, but a set of representative points across the raster are used to generate a framework for the output raster, then it's filled in.

EDIT/NOTE: If transformations are "equation-based" like coordinate frame, position vector, Molodensky-Badekas, etc., it's usually possible to concatenate the parameter values together into a single transformation. We don't do that because there are a significant number of file-based (raster-based) transformations as well where you can't concatenate them together into a single transformation.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "reverse direction"?  Does this just mean that a transformation can work both ways?  i.e. "reverse direction" for the transformation WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983_2011 simply means the transform can be applied both ways WGS1984 TO NAD83 and NAD83 TO WGS1984?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A transformation is defined in a particular direction but all the ArcGIS-supported ones can be applied in either direction.